# Restful service - one call, multiple SQL executions, one response

Tags: java, sql-server, rest

Guys i am quite confused about this one. Assume that i have a object that needs to return 3 different figures taken from database from ***SAME***  (Not different tables as previously stated) by running 3 different SQL statements and unfortunately the SQL statements are a bit complicated and i have no idea how to combine them as of now into single statement. So for the time being i would like to achieve - Request (run 3 separate queries) Response..

I have found [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/306722/Executing-multiple-SQL-statements-as-one-against-S) which is what i would like to have however this is C based and not Java. Do you know of a equivalent?. Or if you have an idea on how to approach this perhaps?

What i have right now is in my php page that displays stuff, i make 3 separate requests to this class, and each request has a unique 'flag'

so i.e.

```
www.something.com?stuff1=stuff1&flag=1
www.something.com?stuff1=stuff1&flag=2
```

and so on, and that returns 3 different figures that i then display on the Page. It works but its not great and i want to make it 'nicer' ;)

**EDIT:**

I am using Spring Framework for this app

Ok So here are the SQL queries i am running against the DB.

```
public String query1() {
        setCurrent("Phone 1");
        return "select sum(case when calltime<60 then 0.035 else ceiling(calltime*3.5*10/60)/1000 end) from call where accountid = "+account.getId()+" and oqannounced is not null"
                + " and (calledback is null or (not ((calledback=2 and agentid is not null)))) and entry>'"+account.getFromDate()+"' and entry < '"+account.getToDate()+"'";
}

public String query2() {
        setCurrent("Phone 2");
        return "select count(1) from call where accountid = "+account.getId()+" and agentid is not null and calledback=2 and entry>'"+account.getFromDate()+"' and entry < '"+account.getToDate()+"'";
}

public String query3() {
        setCurrent("Phone 3");
        return "select sum(case when calltime<60 then 0.004 else ceiling(calltime*0.4*10/60)/1000 end) from call where accountid = "+account.getId()+" and oqannounced is null"
                + " and (calledback is null or (not ((calledback=2 and agentid is not null)))) and entry>'"+account.getFromDate()+"' and entry < '"+account.getToDate()+"'";
}
```

So previously stated that i need to run against 3 different tabled and in fact i do apologize but i was wrong its the same table, so i presume there is a way of joining (and possibly re-factoring) these SQL statements. Note that i have not wrote these statements but other developer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Stored Procedure` that can contain all 3 queries combined, and return results to your code. From that point on prepare JSON/response as you want.

You can find nice tutorial on returning multiple values from MySQL stored procedures [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedures-return-multiple-values/).